# How do I show all UV textures at once?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am UV mapping my model and I don't think there are any problems so far.

However, only when each object is selected it shows the texture.

I want to see textures on all objects, like hair, skin and clothing. But I can only see one at a time when I select it.

I'm using blender v2.79

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on Texture Atlas addon in Addons tab. 
It's a workaround, but there's noting better at the moment. Waiting for 2.8!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIok7SCQ3SA

Comment: I'm confused. I'm just doing a simple character thats all. Everyone elses models can see all colours at all times? Did I do this wrong?

Comment: @anon As with your other questions, I suggest adding images to your question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @anon, the Texture Atlas does exactly what you ask. It temporarily joins several objects in one, that lets you see all of its UV maps on a single texture at once. You can place the maps as you wish, and then press a button in the addon, to kill that joined object, and return your original ones, but this time with all the UVs fitting your singe texture.